# How to parse url to get base url? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I parse urls like

`http://www.1800contacts.com/productlist.aspx?dl=P&source=cj&ac=8.2.0007`

and only get

`http://www.1800contacts.com`

?

PS. Some urls have subdomains etc so I can't use regexps here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to use 'uri' library:

```
require 'uri'
address = 'http://www.1800contacts.com/productlist.aspx?dl=P&source=cj&ac=8.2.0007'
uri = URI.parse(address)
puts "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}"  # => http://www.1800contacts.com
```

Comment: Is there a solution to include non-standard ports, such as http://www.example.com:8080/you-found-me.php ?

Comment: Sure. Change address to `address = 'http://example.com:8080/you-found-me.php'` and it give you following: `uri.port # => 8080`

Answer (score 2):

I like @skojin's answer number 1 (sorry I opened another answer, it's only a long comment) because it makes more general code for both cases:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI "http://www.1800contacts.com/productlist.aspx?dl=P&source=cj&ac=8.2.0007"
uri.query = uri.fragment = nil
uri.path = ""
uri.to_s
# => "http://www.1800contacts.com"

uri = URI "http://example.com:8080/you-found-me.php"
uri.query = uri.fragment = nil
uri.path = ""
uri.to_s
# => "http://example.com:8080"
```

Answer (score 1):

2 alternative ways

```
uri = URI.parse(url); uri.path = ''; uri.query = nil; uri.to_s
url.split('/')[0,3].join('/')
```